# How to only count letters (Aa-Zz) in a really long string with a lot of other characters?

Tags: c#, string

I'm doing this program that is going to read a file with 500k - 1M words in many languages (each line is one word) like this:

```
Árbol
Über
love
UN
A.A.
A&M
computer
a
```

Due to the fact that this file has a lot of words and a lot of other characters, uppercase and lower case letters, in the output I'm getting this:

```
&....1
.....2 //dot
A....3
M....1
N....1
U....1
a....1
b....2
c....1
e....3
l....2
m....1
o....3
p....1
r....3
t....1
u....1
v....1
�....2 //This one is counting (Á and Ü)
```

I need to only get the occurrences of A-Z letters like this:

```
A....5 //including Á and a
B....2
C....1
E....3
L....2
M....2
N....1
O....3
P....1
R....3
T....1
U....2 //including Ü
V....1
```

This is the code I wrote for the character count:

```
    //Extension method for the whole string.
    public static Dictionary<char, int> CharacterCount(this string text)
    {
        return text.GroupBy(c => c)
                   .OrderBy(c => c.Key)
                   .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
    }

    private void getLettersCount()
    {
        List<string> lettersN = new List<string>();

        var counts = text.CharacterCount();

        foreach (var x in counts)
        {
            lettersN.Add(x.Key + "...." + x.Value);
        }

        lettersRTB.Lines = lettersN.ToArray(); //Puts the output in a RichTextBox
    }
```

What can I change in my code to achieve the simplest output like the second one I showed you? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you already tried something? It seems that you already can write code, according to the snippets you provided. What *particular* issues do you have? BTW using LINQ + `GroupBy` on a 1 MB string is highly inefficient.

Comment: Enumerate through the dictionary : foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> chr in dict)

Comment: @dynamoid I tried converting the special characters like Á, á, ä to just A but I couldn't do that, I'm no expert in regular expressions so that's like the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.8) to convert á into a and an accent character. The rest is fairly simple:

```
public Dictionary<char, int> CharacterCount(string text)
{
    Dictionary<char, int> frequency = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        char character = text[i];
        // ignore everything except letters
        if (!char.IsLetter(character)) continue;
        // this will seperate á into a and an accent character, and convert
        // everything to upper case
        var decomposed = character
            .ToString()
            .ToUpper()
            .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

        // take the first character so we get just a from á
        character = decomposed[0];
        // increment frequencies
        int count;
        if (!frequency.TryGetValue(character, out count))
            frequency.Add(character, 0);
        frequency[character] = ++count;
    }

    return frequency;
}
```

Comment: I think this fails to count `&` and to map the frequency of `Á` and `Ü` to whatever `�` is according to the OP requirements

Comment: @taquion I think it's inline with the requirements of OP. See "I need to only get the occurrences of A-Z letters like this:"

Comment: Yes, you are right, I though after reading `//This one is counting (Á and Ü)` that he wanted to map some stuff.. doh

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class to take care of all the logic regarding the processing of the given string. This class will allow you to register all those characters you want to count and also some special rules to map certain characters to whatever character you want, here is a working draft:

```
public class LetterCounter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<char, int> _dictionary;
    private readonly Dictionary<char, char> _specialRules;
    public readonly HashSet<char> _allowedCharacters;

    public LetterCounter()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        _specialRules = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        _allowedCharacters = new HashSet<char>();
    }

    public void RegisterCharacters(string str)
    {
        foreach (var @char in str) _allowedCharacters.Add(@char);
    }

    public void RegisterChar(char @char) => _allowedCharacters.Add(@char);

    public void RegisterCharGroupRule(CharGroupRule rule)
    {
        _allowedCharacters.Add(rule.MainChar);
        foreach (var mappedCharacter in rule.MappedCharacters) _specialRules[mappedCharacter] = rule.MainChar;
    }

    public IEnumerable<(char @char, int count)> ProcessString(string str)
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
        foreach (var @char in str)
        {
            if (!_allowedCharacters.Contains(@char)) continue;

            var localChar = @char;
            if (_specialRules.ContainsKey(localChar)) localChar = _specialRules[localChar];

            if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(localChar)) _dictionary[localChar]++;
            else _dictionary[localChar] = 1;
        }

        return _dictionary.Select(c => (c.Key, c.Value)).OrderBy(c => c.Key);
    }
}
```

And the rule class:

```
public class CharGroupRule
{
    public char MainChar { get; }

    public char [] MappedCharacters { get; }

    public CharGroupRule(char mainChar, char[] mappedCharacters)
    {
        MainChar = mainChar;
        MappedCharacters = mappedCharacters;
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
    var counter = new LetterCounter();
    counter.RegisterCharacters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    counter.RegisterCharacters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToUpper());
    counter.RegisterCharGroupRule(new CharGroupRule('U', new[] {'Ü'}));
    var result = counter.ProcessString("UÜ");
```

I think that this solution avoids hardcoded stuff, and also allows you to map characters the way you want. It is demo code, therefore it lacks of some validations, e.g. with the actual implementation you can define rules that maps the same character to many others, but the last registered rule overwrites previous.

You also avoid the overhead of grouping the entire string, and since the backing data structures we are using are hashsets and dictionaries (hash tables at the end) I think it should be not too bad regarding performance.

The code is also resuable and could allow you to count characters that are not neither characters nor digits like `&`